# Use dplyr to replace values on select columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use the `replace()` function in `dplyr` to clean my data. I want to run it on all the columns except one. If I use a `select()` statement before I lose my character identifiers. I am looking for something like this

```
newdata<-data %>% replace(((.)>1000),0)
```

But with an exception

```
newdata<-data %>% replace(((-StoreID)>1000),0)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you didn't provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), here's how it would work on the `iris` dataset:

```
iris %>% mutate_each(funs(replace(., . > 5, NA)), -Species)
```

We use `mutate_each()` to replace by `NA` the values greater than 5 in all columns except `Species`

---

For your example it would be something like:

```
data %>% mutate_each(funs(replace(., . > 1000, 0)), -StoreID)
```

Comment: out of curiosity, how something similar be used for replace_na instead of replace ?

Comment: what if , I want to run this on only one column? 
will `data %>% mutate_each(funs(replace(., . > 1000, 0)), StoreID)` work?

Comment: is it possible to use `mutate_at` with a modified .vars argument? Something like this: `iris %>% 
  mutate_at(.tbl=., .vars=names(.), funs(replace(., . > 5, NA)))` where the `Species` is substracted from the `names(.)` - anybody can think of a way??

Answer (score 1):

`mutate_each` was deprecated as of `dplyr` version 0.7.0.
Here's an updated answer using `across`:

```
iris %>% mutate(across(-Species, ~replace(., . > 5, NA)))
```