# How to mutate a subset of columns with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this `tbl`

```
data_frame(a_a = letters[1:10], a_b = letters[1:10], a = letters[1:10])
```

And I am trying to substitute all `d` in each column starting with `a_` with the value `new value`.

I thought the below code would do the job, but it doesn't:

```
data_frame(a_a = letters[1:10], a_b = letters[1:10], a = letters[1:10]) %>% 
  mutate_each(vars(starts_with('a_'), funs(gsub('d', 'new value',.))))
```

instead it gives

> Error: is.fun_list(calls) is not TRUE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guiding from [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32483280/use-dplyr-to-replace-values-on-select-columns) and considering `dft` as your input, you can try :

```
dft %>%
  dplyr::mutate_each(funs(replace(., . == "d", "nval")), matches("a_"))
```

which gives:

```
## A tibble: 10 × 3
#     a_a   a_b     a
#   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1      a     a     a
#2      b     b     b
#3      c     c     c
#4   nval  nval     d
#5      e     e     e
#6      f     f     f
#7      g     g     g
#8      h     h     h
#9      i     i     i
#10     j     j     j
```